# Arrangement of letters when we have repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have the following question:

> Four letters are picked from the word EXAMPLES. How many different
> arrangements are there of the $4$ letters?

This was solved the following way:
Number of permutations that do not contain "E" is $P(6,4)=360$

Number of permutations that contain one "E": $4 \cdot P(6,3)=480$ (They basically fixed "E" in every position and checked how many permutations there will be.)

Number of permutations that contain two "E"s: $6 \cdot P(6,2)=180$

Total: $900$ arrangements.

I have two questions:

$1-$ Why did they use permutations with $n=6$? The question asked about the arrangements if the words we take only and not of "EXAMPLES".

$2-$ Why is the second case (if we have one E) special? They don't we count it as if it is any other letter like the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word EXAMPLES has seven distinct letters: E, X, A, M, P, L, S.

Thus, the number of arrangements of four letters drawn from the word EXAMPLES if E is not included is $P(7 - 1, 4) = P(6, 4)$.

The author chose to break down the problem into cases depending on the number of Es the word contains.  It is not necessary to do the problem this way.

The author could have instead solved the problem by considering two cases, arrangements in which all the letters are distinct and those which contain two Es.  There are $P(7, 4)$ arrangements of four distinct letters of the word EXAMPLES.  Notice that
$$P(6, 4) + 4P(6, 3) = 360 + 4 \cdot 120 = 360 + 480 = 840 = P(7, 4)$$
so the author's first two cases could have been folded into one case, namely those arrangements with four distinct letters drawn from the word EXAMPLES.

As for the remaining case in which both Es are used, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose positions for the Es, six ways to fill the leftmost remaining position with a letter other than E, and five ways to fill the remaining open position with one of the letters that has not already been used.  Thus, there are indeed
$$\binom{4}{2}P(6, 2) = 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 = 180$$
such cases.

However, this gives a total of $840 + 180 = 1020$ possible arrangements of four letters of the word EXAMPLES, not $900$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!